# Insuring Jquery Extensions are defined before they are called

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JQuery extension method which get defined. In the same script, on document load, the extension gets called.

I get an occasional error as captured in Azure's Application Insights which tells me that my function that is getting called is not a function.

So clearly the document load is executing before the function can be defined. In short it looks something like this (***this is in a single JavaScript file***)

```
(function ($) {
  if (!$.myFunc) {
    $.extend({
      myFunc: function(params) { ... }
    });
  }
})(jQuery);

$(function(){
  $.myFunc(blahblah);
});
```

The error ends up being:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $.myFunc is not a function
```

The error only occasionally happens, so this is a race condition.

How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: If that's really what your code looks like, it seems to me that what you're describing is impossible. The IIFE will complete before the code that registers the "ready" handler, let alone before the handler itself would fire.

Comment: One thing that *can* cause such a problem is if another copy of jQuery is imported sometime between the extension definition and its attempted use.

Comment: @Pointy believe me, that's what has me stumped. That is what the code looks like.  I can't see a way a 2nd jquery is getting loaded, and this only happens occasionally and I'm unable to reproduce the error as of yet locally. It's a head scratcher!

Comment: Well when I've had bizarre situations like that, I've usually resorted to sprinkling `console.log("A")`, `console.log("B")` messages in the code, along with tests to (for example) make sure the extension still exists. That way you can triangulate on the part of the code where the problem is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so @Pointy pointed me in the right direction. There is some conditional code which is loading a different layout page in the _ViewStart.cshtml, and that layout page is duplicating Jquery! Looks like some old code, as the viewstart is specific to that registered area.

Thanks @Pointy